# Apps script .getValue() returning #N/A

Tags: google-apps-script, getvalue

I'm having an issue with this apps script that's attempting to add data to my Google Cloud database. The problem variables are Open, High, Low, Close; which are all values found by formulas in the 'RAW' sheet. The formulas behind Open, High, Low, Close looks like this:

`=round(index(B6:B35,match($A$3,$A$6:$A$35,0))/index(AUD!C:C,match(A3,AUD!A:A,0)),8)`

When the query tries to execute the getValue() is returning #N/A, as is getDisplayValue(), which doesn't align with the table parameters.

The problem only occurs when the reference cells include formulas, when I change those cells to integers to test it goes through to the db no problem.

Is there a different way to do this, or stop getValue() returning #N/A?

Many thanks!

OM.

```
function insert() {

// RAW Variables
  var date_  = Utilities.formatDate(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW').getRange('A3').getValue(), "GMT+10", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var open_  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW').getRange('B3').getValue()
  var high_  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW').getRange('C3').getValue()
  var low_   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW').getRange('D3').getValue()
  var close_ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW').getRange('E3').getValue()
  var volume_= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW').getRange('F3').getValue()

// Connection Variables
  var connectionName = '.....';
  var user = '.....';
  var userPwd = '......';
  var db = '.....';
  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName + '/' + db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement()

// Query  
  var query="insert into test(Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) values('"+date_+"','"+open_+"','"+high_+"','"+low_+"','"+close_+"','"+volume_+"')"

  stmt.execute(query)
  stmt.close()
  conn.close()
 }
```

Update:

Adding iferror() to the begging of the formulas I was able to get the error value through to the table, however that's not an ideal result for me.

The fact that getValue() or getDisplayValues() doesn't return the *result* of the formula is my biggest concern. What is most strange is that the right most column is also a formula: `=index(F6:F35,match($A$3,$A$6:$A$35,0))`

The only difference between that formula and the problem ones is a division operator '/'. Any thoughts regarding that?

Outside of testing on the insert query I've also been testing by using the Open, High.. to cell.setValue(), within sheets, and getting the same #N/A result.

```js
| 2018-05-13 | 11278.421244330 | 11620.21125128 | 11118.99605973 | 11554.50481772 |  5866380000 |
| 2018-05-14 | 11576.562811400 | 11799.80070418 | 11118.00969906 | 11581.46548861 |  7364150000 |
| 2018-05-15 | 11657.201395350 | 11832.62472130 | 11324.11133355 | 11396.32950125 |  6705710000 |
| 2018-05-16 |     0.000000000 |     0.00000000 |     0.00000000 |     0.00000000 |  6760220000 |
+------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Result from insert query ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) to eliminate N/A and #DIV/0!

```
=IFERROR(formula, "value to display if an error occurs")
```

I can't test yours but I'd say this is what you are looking for:

```
=IFERROR(round(index(B6:B35,match($A$3,$A$6:$A$35,0))/index(AUD!C:C,match(A3,AUD!A:A,0)),8), 0)
```

getValue() will now always return 0 or the result.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, iferrror() sort of worked, however still not the result I am after. I've added some additional info above and the results of your suggestion. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to get information from a query with importrange. I think you can't use data from an importrange as a value, though it could be the combination of have both. If your index value in the formula is an importrange data it probably is the reason.

I was trying to make a dynamic formula to paste on my sheets based on the selected column. It kept giving the #N/A while I tried to get information of the column from the importrange. As soon as I went from a match that used the importrange data to a calculated way to determine the column it worked.